# SEO of print pages

Tags: html, seo, canonical-link

I'm interested in SEO of print pages. I have a page with an article and a link to the same address with the suffix /print/, which then shows the came content, but with a print-like stylesheet.

This creates duplicities in search results, because both pages are the same, just the address is a bit different.

I already did a little research on this topic and there are a few options to use:

- set `rel=canonical` to the original page from the print pagee
- `meta` `noindex` for the print page
- `rel=nofollow` for links

What do you think is the best solution?

Comment: change the stylesheet on the one page

Comment: Agreed @checkenginelight. Link a stylesheet with `media='print'` and it will be used when the document is sent to the printer. But displayed on screen will look the same.

Answer (score 5):

1. As suggested above, use a special stylesheet for the printing of your pages. [Good tutorial here](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml). This is the preferred method as you don't have to make two pages just so one can be printer friendly. That means no duplicate content issues and less pages for you to maintain.
2. Use rel="canonical" on the print version of the page. No need to use noindex or nofollow if the canonical URL is specified.

Comment: Ok, thx. Users are sometimes afraid to print ordinary pages, because when there is no print stylesheet specified, the printer prints loads of papers full of menus, ads, so it seems more friendly to have a link to a print page for them to see what they are printing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a javascript to change your stylesheet. This way you'll have an actual link people can click on.

If you want to hide your menu, ads etc just use `display: none` for those elements in the print stylesheet.

Here's a link to the script:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/stylesheetswitcher.htm